# Opening keyboard in Ionic iOS app moves the background image up

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor

When opening the keyboard in iOS the background image of my ion-content is moved up. How can I stop this?
I am using Capacitor not Cordova.

[image]

[image]

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="content">

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  background: url("./../../../assets/img/login-bg.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
}
```

I have a solution for Android already in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For iOS add this to capacitor.config.json

```
{
  "plugins": {
    "Keyboard": {
      "resize": "body",
      "style": "dark"
    }
  }
}
```

See documentation here: https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/keyboard

For Android:
Add this to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Comment: How I' do that in ionic v4 ( I don't use capacitor )